# Java floating-point numbers representation as a hexadecimal numbers

Tags: java, floating-point, hex

Why does `0x1p3` equal `8.0`? Why does `0x1e3` equal `483`, whereas `0x1e3d` equals `7741`? It is confusing since `1e3d` equals `1000.0`.

Comment: @marcog this is part of a way to express floating point numbers, see the JLS: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.2

Comment: @marcog: that's the exponent marker for a hexadecimal floating point literal, as defined in the Java and C99 standards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`0x1e3` and `0x1e3d` are hexadecimal **integer** literals. Note that `e` and `d` are hexadecimal digits, not the exponent indicator or `double` type indicator in this case.

`1e3d` is a decimal **floating-point** literal. The `e` is the exponent indicator, the `d` says that this is a `double` rather than a `float`.

The notation `0x1p3` is a way to express a floating-point literal in hexadecimal, as you can read in [section 3.10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) of the Java Language Specification. It means 1 times 2 to the power 3; the exponent is binary (so, it's 2-to-the-power instead of 10-to-the-power).

Comment: But 0x1p3 should be as same as 1e3 in this case, right? But they are not.

Comment: @serious No, because the exponent is binary, not decimal. Its 2^3 not 10^3.

Comment: Btw, is there any reason why it is binary? I mean, why it is not base of 16?

Comment: Base 16 (hex) is a human construction to help us manage long strings of bits without going mad.  In a computer, it's all binary - there's no hex.  Note that one binary nybble (4 bits) maps directly to 1 hex digit. So the byte 11010111 becomes (1101)(0111) = 0xD7.

Comment: Yes, but in the 1e3 notation exponent is decimal.

Comment: in 0x1e3 there is no exponent.  That's an integer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 0x1p3d which contains binary exponent (as mentioned before by Jesper) as opposite to 1e3d with "decimal" exponent.

Comment: I don't know why with the p-notation the exponent is binary. This notation is something that Java inherited from C or C++. It's hard to find out after the fact why someone somewhere long ago thought this would be a useful feature...

Comment: @serious, you're getting your terminology and representations mixed up.  1e3d doesn't mean the 3 is in decimal.  According to jesper, it means the value is a _double_.  If this isn't what you meant, then the confusion might be that the default representation in Java is decimal.  So 1e3 is 1000 base 10.  0x1p3 is 8 since the 0x means "this representation is in hex".  The reason 'e' is not used for the hex floating point exponent is that it probably leads to an ambiguous situation - 'e' is a valid hex digit, 'p' is not.  Thus 'p' is never ambiguous.

Comment: Checking the spec linked waaay above, we see that if 'e' were allowed to denote a floating point literal's exponent, then 0x1e3 would be ambiguous. Is it the integer 483 or is it the floating point 8?  The (perhaps ham-handed) 'p' removes this ambiguity.

Comment: @Jesper: It's an extraordinarily useful feature, whether or not you see a use for it.  In particular, it makes it quite easy straightforward to exactly specify a floating point constant without any rounding.

Answer (score 2):

0x1e3 is hex for 483, as is 0x1e3d hex for 7741. The `e` is being read as a hex digit with value 14.

Comment: Ah, 0x1e3 is a hex number, so "e" doesn't mean an exponent here.

Comment: @serious, the difference is that 0x1e3 is an integer, not a floating point number.  The 'e' in that integer is just an unfortunate coincidence that confuses.  0x1p3 is a floating point number.  It is interpreted _very_ differently.  The interpretation includes a _mantissa_ and an _exponent_.  The former is the 1.0 part (note the assumed decimal point.)  The latter is the 'p3' part which which reads 'to the 3rd power.'  Since we're in binary, taking a number to to the 3rd power is the same as shifting it 3 bits to the left, so the 0b1 becomes 0b1000.  That's 8 in decimal.