# Java - curious number declaration

Tags: java

I have found somewhere a pretty weird number declaration in Java.

```
double x = 0xap-001;
```

I am curious why the value of x is 5.0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546532/java-floating-point-numbers-representation-as-a-hexadecimal-numbers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

p indicates a binary exponentiation.  So you have hex 0xa == 10, with a binary exponent of -1 - in other words a shift right or div 2. The result is 10/2 = 5.